# ImportError: No module named robots

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

When I try to start the server, this error occurred:

```
ImportError: No module named robots
```

I have tried to use pip:

```
pip install robots
```

but there is no such module

traceback as follow:

```
(env) U:\Python\mdknowledge>python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "manage.py", line 8, in <module>
            execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
          File "U:\Python\mdknowledge\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__ini
        t__.py", line 399, in execute_from_command_line
            utility.execute()
          File "U:\Python\mdknowledge\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__ini
        t__.py", line 392, in execute
            self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
          File "U:\Python\mdknowledge\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.
        py", line 242, in run_from_argv
            self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
          File "U:\Python\mdknowledge\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.
        py", line 280, in execute
            translation.activate('en-us')
          File "U:\Python\mdknowledge\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\translation\__i
        nit__.py", line 130, in activate
            return _trans.activate(language)
          File "U:\Python\mdknowledge\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\translation\tra
        ns_real.py", line 188, in activate
            _active.value = translation(language)
          File "U:\Python\mdknowledge\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\translation\tra
        ns_real.py", line 177, in translation
            default_translation = _fetch(settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)
          File "U:\Python\mdknowledge\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\translation\tra
        ns_real.py", line 159, in _fetch
            app = import_module(appname)
          File "U:\Python\mdknowledge\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\importlib.py",
        line 40, in import_module
            __import__(name)
        ImportError: No module named robots
```

try pip:

```
        (env) U:\Python\mdknowledge>pip install robots
        Collecting robots
          Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement robots (from versions:
         )
        No matching distribution found for robots
```

Comment: So, silly question, what is the robots module? What is telling you to install/use it?

Comment: Is `robots` one of the `INSTALLED_APPS` from your `settings.py`? Are you trying to use e.g. [`django-robots`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-robots)?

Comment: You may want to read the instructions, it is `pip install django-robots` not `pip install robots` - but one can dream...

Comment: Why were you trying to use it in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pip install django-robots`

Read the [install](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-robots) instructions